# Possibitity of forgetting an umbrella

Tags: probability

The probability of someone forgetting their umbrella in a store is equal to 1/3. After visiting 2 stores in a row, he discovers that he forgot his umbrella in one of them. What is the probability that he forgot his umbrella in the 2nd store?

I was wondering if it is Bayes theorem problem, but I found difficulty in computing the data of Bayes type.
I would appreciate for your quidance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As reminded in the comments, we know he forgot his umbrella!

Let $A=$ forgot in Store $1$.

and $B=$ forgot in Store $2$.

$$\begin{aligned} 
P(B|A\texttt{ OR } B) &= \frac{P(A\texttt{ OR }B|B)P(B)}{P(A\texttt{ OR } B)}\\
 &= \frac{P(A\texttt{ OR }B|B)P(B|\texttt{ NOT }A)P(\texttt{NOT} A)}{P(A)+P(B|\texttt{NOT }A)P(\texttt{NOT }A)}\\
&= \frac{1 \cdot 2/9}{1/3 + 2/9}=\frac{2}{5}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is the a priori probability. How did you take into account that the man did lose his umbrella somewhere?

Comment: We are also given that he forgot his umbrella in one of the first two stores.

Comment: Okay, will correct it ...   Thank you for the comments!  You are right!

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional probability. Hints:

- What is the probability he lost his umbrella in the first store?
- What is the probability he did not lose his umbrella in the first store?
- What is the probability he lost his umbrella in the second store?
- What is the probability he lost his umbrella in the first or the second store?
- What is the probability he lost his umbrella in the second store given that he lost his umbrella in one of the stores?

Comment: Thank you very much! So I used Bayes theorem and I found that the conditional possibitity is (2/9):(1/3+2/9) = 2/5. Is my way of thinking correct? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @kostas So what do you think the answer is? We can help you check it

Comment: Perfect! I reached the result that the conditional possibitity is equal to 2/5. Is it correct? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @kostas Yes.  I get $\frac{2/9}{5/9} =\frac25$ too

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I would like to ask for your guidance for how to find the conditional possibitity P(A/AUB).         
I wrote it as P[ΑU(AΛΒ)]/P(AUB) but then I stucked. We are given that P(A) =P(B) = a and that A, B are independent. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kostas $A \cup(A\cap B) = A$.  In fact you want $P(A \mid  B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ where $A$ is the event of losing the umbrella in the second store, and $B$ is the event of losing the umbrella: they are not independent and $P(A \cap B)=P(A)$ here though not in other questions.  Not are the events of losing it in the first and of losing it in the second independent, as losing in the first prevents a loss in the second.

Comment: It is clear, you helped me a lot! Thank you very much!